# DATENAME and DATEPART in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

I'm trying to get my EntryDate column in this format 'YYYY_m' for example '2013_04'.

This code has been unsuccessful

```
DATENAME (YYYY, EntryDate) + '_' + DATEPART (M, EntryDate)
```

Attempts using DATEFORMAT have also been unsuccessful, stating there was syntax error at ','  after the M. What code would work instead?

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?  It is tagged MySQL but the code snippet is screaming SQL Server.

Comment: "unsuccessful" doesn't mean anything.  Post the actual error you received.

Comment: Apologizes it is SQL Server and its says there is a syntax error near ','     . The one after M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `date_format()`?

```
select date_format(EntryDate, '%&Y_%m')
```

This is the MySQL way.  Your code looks like an attempt to do this in SQL Server.

EDIT:

The following should work in SQL Server:

```
select DATENAME(year, EntryDate) + '_' + RIGHT('00' + DATEPART(month, EntryDate), 2)
```

Personally, I might use `convert()`:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(7), EntryDate, 121), '-', '_')
```

Comment: Sorry I meant SQL server, I'm fairly new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATENAME (YYYY, EntryDate) 
      + '_' 
      + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),datepart (MM, EntryDate)), 2)
```

You have to convert the result of `DATEPART()` to a character string in order for the `+` to perform an append.

FYI - in the future "unsuccessful" doesn't mean anything.  Next time post the actual error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
SELECT concat(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2015/1/1'), '_', 
         LPAD(extract(month from '2014/1/1'),2,'0')) AS OrderYear
```

This uses

- concat to combine strings
- lpad to place a leading 0 if month is one digit
- and uses extract to pick of the part of date needed.

working fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63b24/8

Answer (score 0):

DATEPART
It is a Datetime function which extract information from date. This function always returns result as integer type.

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, '2009-01-01 00:00:00:000') as month
it is return "1" as an integer:
```

DATENAME
It is also another Datetime function which to extract information from date. This function always returns result as varchar

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, '2009-01-01 00:00:00:000')  as month
it is return "January".
```